# Limpiar Formulario en Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Tengo un Formulario en donde al momento de llenar los campos y presionar el botón guardar, los datos todavía se quedan ahí, ¿existe alguna forma de que cuando presione el botón se limpie el formulario?, hasta el momento uso un botón llamado cancelar que me limpia el formulario.

Aquí esta el HTML:

```
<mat-card-actions>
    <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="save()" [disabled]="currentTask.taskName===''|| currentTask.startDate==='' || currentTask.asOfDate===''" *ngIf="currentTask.id===-1">Guardar</button>
    <button mat-raised-button color="accent" (click)="edit()" [disabled]="currentTask.taskName===''|| currentTask.startDate==='' || currentTask.asOfDate===''" *ngIf="currentTask.id===-1">Editar</button>
    <button mat-raised-button color="warn" (click)="cancel()">Cancelar</button>
</mat-card-actions>
```

y en esta parte esta el TS:

```
    save(){
    this.rest.post("/project",{
      projectName: this.currentProject.projectName,
      projectStatus: this.currentProject.projectStatus,
      projectManager: this.currentProject.projectManager,
      startDate: this.currentProject.startDate,
      asOfDate: this.currentProject.asOfDate,
      client: this.currentProject.client
    }).subscribe(result =>{
      this.common.addProjectData(1)
      
    })
  }
  edit(){
    this.rest.put("/project/"+this.currentProject.id,{
      projectName: this.currentProject.projectName,
      projectManager: this.currentProject.projectManager,
      projectStatus: this.currentProject.projectStatus,
      startDate: this.currentProject.startDate,
      asOfDate: this.currentProject.asOfDate,
      client: this.currentProject.client
    }).subscribe(result =>{
      this.common.addProjectData(1)
    })
  }
  cancel(){
    this.currentProject.projectName = "";
    this.currentProject.projectManager ="";
    this.currentProject.projectStatus= "";
    this.currentProject.startDate ="";
    this.currentProject.asOfDate= "";
    this.currentProject.client="";
  }
```

Comment: Dentro del `subscribe` de la función `save` llama a la función `cancel()`

Answer (score 1):

Si estas utilizando un formGroup, puedes utilizar la propiedad "this.currentProject.reset()"